# Accent reduction

Tags: accent

How can I correct my prononcitaion of the words and reduce my accent? I am not able to pronounce the english words properly and therefore runinto people not undersatnding me.

Comment: I'm not sure we can solve this in a text post.  Maybe check out the film "My Fair Lady"?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. Your question is rather broad, as we don't know what your accent is like, nor what your audience expects. Ultimately, the answer is the same as it would be for any language— get a good coach, or study recordings of yourself and of people speaking the accent you wish to emulate. We have a collection of [pronunciation resources](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/1057/21), and you might also review *[How to Improve Intonation?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/26113)* or *[How to improve or get rid of an Indian English Accent?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/16719)* for ideas.

Comment: While _prononcitation_ (which is what I think you were trying to write) is a very clever coinage (which may remind Americans of their former President George W. Bush) it is not a real word in English. Have you consultified a dictionary to learn the noun we use to describe what results when we _pronounce_ a word?

Comment: Our _Community Wiki_ has a page with many resources which may assist you: it is called [**Resources for learning English.**](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english)

Comment: I spend a lot of time listening to non-native Anglophones on streamed lectures, debates, etc. (so they're invariably clever, well-educated people). One particular problem I notice more with Indians than anyone else is their tendency to speak very quickly when they *do* know exactly how best to express some small subsection within an utterance, then slow down again when they get to less familiar parts. If I'm attuned to the primary (slower) rate, I may not catch the rapid (often, *slurred*) part. So I suggest that *Try to maintain a constant delivery speed* would be worth bearing in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Different strategies will be better suited to different people, but I will tell you what helped me the most in improving my English pronunciation: **learning general phonetics**. By general, I mean studying phonetics independent from a language. Do not start with anything focusing on English phonetics nor Hindi phonetics (or whichever is your native language).

Start by learning the basic concepts of phonetics; once you've got a good base, move on to learn the specifics of English phonetics and that of your native language. Note that it is important for you to study the phonetics of your own language as well, in order to avoid some imperceptible features that are not present in English. For example, I found out that in my language vowels are [murmured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murmured_voice) after the stressed syllable. I had never noticed it despite having used my language nearly every day ever since I was a child, but by having learned this I am able to avoid doing the same thing when speaking English.

This has, in fact, helped me much more than immersion (living in an English-speaking country). At first, my fluency suffered because I had to pay a lot more attention to the details when pronouncing anything, but in the long run my accent has become much more similar to native dialects.