# Attitudes and concerns over Indian-English accent

Tags: spoken-english, accent

What are common attitudes and concerns over the Indian-English accent (see [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6Xg8FH643U&t=50s)) among those who are teaching or learning in ESL? How do these attitudes make the Indian accent compare with others, such as  American, Welsh, Scottish, Australian, Caribbean?

My question is related to teaching and learning. Most people seem to prefer an American or British (RP) accent while learning English. I am asking because I want to select an accent for further practice.

Comment: This question will probably (and perhaps rightly) be closed due to being based on opinion. If you want to speak to people in India and be understood, then Indian English will obviously be effective but (opinion coming) it **may not be** be prestigious. If you want to speak to people in the U.S. and sound like a native, then Indian English is objectively ineffective, but (opinion coming) it is not considered by most people as **socially deficient** if the only material difference is accent. So I believe the question can be answered without necessarily expressing an opinion.

Comment: @JeffMorrow I personally would like to know where your scope of the "English" goes. Sure, currently the U.S accent is the dominant, but the English is English, then how far can we encompass the "map" of English as the "standard English"?

Comment: There is an interesting question hiding in there.  Certainly it is customary in some places to teach General American English, and in others to teach RP/Oxford; but are there places outside the Subcontinent where Indian English is customarily taught?

Comment: @AntonSherwood None probably. Because their main language is mostly Hindu.

Comment: @Kentaro Hind**i** is the first language of about a third of Indians.  The lack of a majority language is part of the reason for the continuing importance of English in India.

Comment: Thinking of it, **this *could* be a research question rather than opinion** if we were to collect official statements from, like, faculty and/or such as national language institutes that *could* be considered qualified to speak for "the ESL TL community". That is, if, with all the PC padding, definitive answers are still to be had.

Comment: @JeffMorrow: While the phraseology of this question might not distinguish it, as reliably as might be hoped, from an opinion-based one, the core premise is essentially fact oriented. Among those teaching ESL, any of them either may specifically instruct students on Indian pronunciation, or may not do so. Further, any might provide reasons. Whereas such reasons might follow from individual opinions, it is fact that the reasons are given by such people. As the question essentially addresses the composition of the ESL community, I suggest it may be answered factually, at least in principle.

Comment: @JeffMorrow The only part of this question that is opinion-based is "why people prefer American or British accents". The title question, of whether it is "recognised" is a matter of fact.

Comment: @epi and Astralbee I think the comment that you are referring to makes clear that the question can **possibly** be answered without resorting to opinion. An answer, however, based on a hypothetical survey that has not actually been taken is not a fact; it is a guess or an opinion. Moreover, millions of people speak Indian English. Therefore, in one sense, asking whether it is "recognized" is a remarkably silly question. If we mean something more, then we are asking about what definition is to be ascribed to "recognize" in this context. Opinions will differ on that.

Comment: @JeffMorrow: 1) While it is clear that the choice of words is imperfect, such observation is not a reason to make such a deeply uncharitable extrapolation of intent. 2) The observation of some methodology being difficult to undertake, or never having been undertaken, does not support a conclusion that a question is strictly opinion based. 3) *Hundreds* of millions of people speak Indian English. Again, such observation (which can be factually verified), does not support a conclusion that a question is silly or unanswerable (which are not the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## English  Around the World

English teachers generally would not identify any variety of speech as "authentic", because this word has specific moral and social significance outside the scope of learning a language. However, for educational purposes, each teacher or school generally will identify some dialect as a model for the rules and habits to teach students. In places with no significant population that speaks English, students usually learn following either a British or American standard. This choice usually depends on region or country.

A teacher or school will generally choose either a British or American  standard, and in  particular a [Received Pronunciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation) (RP) or [General American](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_American_English) (GA) accent,  because they are most familiar to English speakers across the world, and so  learning one of them makes it easiest for a student to understand others, and to be understood by them.

Rarely does anyone speak completely as British or Americans unless  native, and not all native to the United Kingdom or even to England speak RP, or to the United States speak  GA. However, how well someone communicates  with native speakers of England or the US may provide a useful test for how well that individual may communicate internationally in English, simply because others will likely use a similar standard. In this sense, many would consider the British and American dialects to  be neutral standards, which create a balancing effect, on the worldwide use of the language. Some may further consider this influence to elevate British or American English to a position of privilege, but such specific characterization is generally not helpful, and often leads to inaccurate conclusions and harmful behaviors.

## English in India

In India and the other countries of South Asia that follow from the influence of British rule, the [combined count of individuals who speak English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_English-speaking_population)  is almost as great as   in the United States, and is more than twice as great as the combined count in the United Kingdom, Canada, and Australia.
[Indian English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_English) is a distinct standard, which determines how students study English in India and nearby countries.

Outside of South Asia, however, students are unlikely to be instructed in speaking English as do Indians.

## Indian Accents Around the  World

Those who understand English generally, tend to understand Indian English. [Certain  features of Indian speech](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16719) sometimes cause difficulties for non-Indians to understand Indians in English. The degree and effect of these features depends on the individual speaker. Sometimes, but not always, these differences diminish naturally for Indians after having moved overseas.

Many native speakers of English have limited experience listening to Indians, whereas a larger proportion of Indians may have regular exposure to British and American media. Such disparities sometimes cause surprises.
An individual accustomed to speaking English among other Indians, as well as to hearing English from both Indian and foreign sources, may feel confused or frustrated during  first conversations with non-Indians, because of difficulty being  understood.

Someone affected by or concerned with these differences may choose simply to modify habits when speaking English, without trying to  mimic speakers born elsewhere.

## Acquiring a New Accent

Many factors may affect a choice to acquire some particular accent.

Some may be motivated by the social perception of a [*prestige accent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prestige_%28sociolinguistics%29),  one historically favored by some privileged group, and considered to represent elevated social status. Historically, RP and GA are the prestige accents of England and the United States. However, their role in each society is not the same. While up to two-thirds of US-born speakers may use GA, it is unlikely that more than one-tenth of English-born speakers naturally use RP.

Some may learn a certain accent  to avoid being the target of bigotry, or to relieve anxiety about feeling foreign. Either is a worthy reason, but none is essentially linguistic, and  may relate to a problem that is better resolved by other means.

For most, being understood is the essential concern. Flexibility with respect to specific habits, not complete transformation, may have the most practical benefit. Some may seek to acquire a specific accent, however, and doing so  is a deeply personal choice, according to taste, objectives, and principles.

Comment: Accent is one thing, speech (grammatical speech) is another. You can have an "Indian accent" and still speak good English, even if you use certain preferences Indians prefer.

Comment: Indian accents around the world? There is more than one?

Comment: @Lambie Yeah I would say there is absolutely more than one. If I can think of one nation on this planet that is the farthest thing from a monolith, it's got to be India.

Comment: @EddieKal Indian Accents Around the World, What is meant is: Having an Indian Accent Outside India.

Comment: @EddieKal: Yes, and there is more than one accent in England, and Southeast England, and London. Even RP and GA have many, in some sense, uncountable, varieties. Accents present on a continuum. One may as well gripe over whether the Aegean Sea is part of, or separate from, the Mediterranean Sea.

Answer (score 3):

OK I am going to try to answer this.

Historically, the same language spoken in disparate places at one time has evolved and become different and mutually unintelligible languages over time. Example: Latin evolved into many different languages and dialects; few who live in Lisbon can understand those who live in Bucharest although the languages spoken in both cites are both descended from Vulgar Latin. Nor does being a native born Frisian make one fluent in Gujarati even though both share a distant linguistic ancestor almost certainly spoken in the Southern Eurasian steppes. In the age of the internet, pop music, and movies, how and at what rate languages will evolve in the future may change from historical norms. I doubt, however, that English will be spoken anywhere in a thousand years exactly as it is today in Tulsa, Sheffield, or Melbourne.

Which variant of a language is considered "best" is not a linguistic question at all. It depends on criteria that are social and economic. If you want to be employed at a high salary in the U.S. in 2020, it is professionally advantageous on average to avoid what the Brits used to call "babu English" and to have an accent that is readily intelligible to Americans. Similarly, if you want to be employed at a high salary in the U.S. in 2020, speaking in working-class Sheffield or Glaswegian will likely be quite disadvantageous because 99% of the population of the U.S. will not even realize that you are speaking a language related to English. If, however, you would rather be dead than live in the U.S., utter ignorance of American idioms and accent is probably of immaterial importance unless you feel a compulsion to learn what the latest Marvel heroes movie is about.

In other words, how you **speak** English derives whatever importance it may or may not have to you from whatever are your social and economic goals and context. If you expect to live in Delhi, cultivating an American accent is probably a waste of effort. If you are hoping to prosper in Green Bay, Wisconsin, getting a bit of American flavor into your English may provide some helpful social lubricant from time to time.

Comment: That entire first paragraph has zero to do with the question, in fact.

Comment: I concur with the earlier opinion expressing a discrepancy of the content of the question, compared to the thematic emphasis of this answer. Whereas the question narrowly addresses the activities of ESL teachers and whatever justification they might give, this answer unnecessarily, even if not inaccurately, laments at the futility of ascribing to any dialect a superior social status.

Comment: I strongly disagree. The question asks what is "recognized and authentic." That is not a question of linguistics at all, but a social and economic question. I have tried to explain, in a fair amount of detail, that language has and always has had variants. Which variant is "recognized" is really a question of "recognized by whom." Which variant is "authentic" is really a question of "authentic among what group at what time and on what occasions." A teacher who does not stress the social dimensions of this question ill serves students.

Comment: That language varies, as do individuals in their background and preferences, is completely beside the point. It has never been questioned, and needs no elaboration. It is also irrelevant whether someone considers the question one of linguistics versus society. If some group teaches Indian English, and another does not, then the answer should  explain this difference, not lament over the fact or cause of the variation.

Comment: I did not lament. What I said is that what you want to learn should depend on why you want to learn it. Which is pretty much where you ended up in your answer by saying that it was a "deeply personal choice."

Comment: Sure, we may have similar views about a choice being personal, but you seem to follow a circuitous route toward undoing some supposed bigotry or ignorance, which perhaps you think is a premise of the question. Essentially this question is 1) what is the role of Indian English in educational institutions in various parts of the world, and 2) how might such observations inform an individual course of study, particularly for accent. Language evolution is irrelevant. Ethnic slurs are irrelevant. Sheffield vernacular is irrelevant. Affirming common lineage is nice poetically, but also irrelevant.

Comment: The explicit premise of the question is that there is a "recognized and authentic" accent. That is nonsense, and I have explained why. But you are correct. We have nothing to say to each other.

Comment: We may not have. I hoped that there might be some openness to the possibility that the question simply lacked perfect word choice, but now I begin to wonder whether you simply prefer that the author of the question is someone with misconceptions that you can correct.

Comment: Accents and varieties of English are two different things altogether. The question is not what your accent is:the question is: How clear is your speech? You can have an accent in English and still speak clearly.

Comment: @Lambie I am not going to argue with you, but this question has been edited to say something totally different from what was originally asked about a "recognized and authentic" English accent. I am tired of having epi try to infer my psychological state of mind for saying that there can be no such thing. Had you responded earlier by suggesting that my comment would have been clearer had I said "accent" rather than "variety," I might have agreed although I am not sure that the original question was intended to be limited to only the different accent of Indian English. It may have been broader.

Comment: The comment you reference was given not because you noted that no particular accents are "recognized and authentic", but because you made the precise meanings of these words the entire focus not only of your response, but also of the broader discussion around the question. as though someone is required to adopt the most erudite mode of communication simply to be allowed to ask a question. Incidentally, that fixation was also the reason why I submitted a revision, which omits the distracting language.

Comment: @epi I hear you, Jeff. Your answer epi is full of inaccuracy. At least, Jeff's answer has the merit of making the main point, which is that an accent is irrelevant. What is relevant is being able to understand a person. Anyway, this question should be removed.

Comment: @Lambie Again, not in a disputatious spirit, I agree that, strictly speaking, I was not distinguishing between accent and dialect. Quite frankly, I didn't think that the OP had that distinction in mind and am still not sure whether he did in fact. And I further agree with you that the **most important issue** is comprehensibility. But I was trying to say more than that, namely that social and economic considerations **are** highly relevant to what accent many people may wish to learn, however much we may wish that only comprehensibility should be considered relevant.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Yes, comprehensibility, I agree with you 100%. I am a natural language interpreter and happen to know a thing or two about accents. No one cares what your accent is as long as you can be understood clearly. In fact, a cute little French accent can, in some circumstances, boost your business, for example. And, the BBC hires speakers for their light non-native accents in English for voiceovers...

Answer (score 3):

"Indian English" isn't just an accent, it is a widely recognised and spoken *variety*, or *dialect* of English.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_English) states that Indian English is "the regional variant of the English language spoken in the Republic of India, and among the Indian diaspora elsewhere in the world". [This article](https://cudoo.com/blog/different-varieties-of-english-language/) lists Indian English alongside other varieties of English, which include British English, American English, Australian English and others. Numerically speaking, Indian English is more widely spoken than British English, so it most certainly is "recognised".

The difference between an **accent** and a **dialect** is that an accent is simply how one pronounces words, whereas a dialect includes not just pronunciations, but also one's general vocabulary and grammar. It is generally easier to adapt to a new dialect than lose one's accent. For example, I'm a British English speaker, but I've watched enough Hollywood movies to know that Americans call the front of a car (what I'd normally call the "bonnet") a "hood", and the rear (the "boot") is called a "trunk". While in America, I'd quickly and easily switch to using those, and other terms, in order to be understood. If I stayed there long enough, using such terms would probably become natural to me. To Americans, I'd be speaking their language but with a British accent.

Likewise, Indian English speakers living in the USA or the UK will no doubt quickly adapt to any new vocabulary, but may still speak with an accent. Rightly or wrongly, they would likely be described as "speaking with an Indian accent".

I can't really say why some people, as you say, "prefer" to hear British or American accents - that is a matter or opinion. I can only assume that through media like television and film, many non-English speakers are most familiar with these accents and therefore find them easier to understand. Personally, I have no problem understanding English when spoken with an Indian accent and have no "preference". I love hearing the rich variety of accents.

I should like to add that I am aware the term "Indian" is often used to describe anything that originates from the entire Indian subcontinent, or South Asia, not just the Republic of India. Likely, when people refer to an "Indian accent", they refer to a broad range of different accents from that area of the world. Similarly, there are many different regional accents within both the UK and the USA.

Comment: The question does not conflate an accent with a dialect broadly, only it makes the former its particular subject.

Comment: @epl I didn't suggest they had confused the two. They asked specifically if Indian English is a recognised accent. My point is that, if it is a recognised dialect, it must logically be a recognised accent, because a dialect incorporates both pronunciation and vocabulary.

Comment: If the difference is understood, why commit half the text to explaining it? Isn't it irrelevant to the information being sought?

Comment: @epl I don't think it is irrelevant at all. Frame challenges make up quite a lot of the correct answers on Stack Exchange, because often, especially on this site, the OP doesn't have enough knowledge of the subject to ask the right question. It's simple logic that if Indian English is a dialect along with American English and Australian English, then an Indian accent sits right alongside American accents and Australian accents. With respect to the OP, they cannot have fully understood the concept of accents and dialects to ask this.

Comment: This is only decent answer. It shows a linguist's knowledge of the reality which nobody else has. And I will repeat here again: having an accent and speaking a variety of English are not necessarily the same thing. Everyone forgets the very charming Caribbean English accents. Just listen to Derek Walcott: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GOlbD_Gawis A true Caribbean English accent and also very educated. He won the Noble Prize.

Answer (score -2):

No, Indian accents of English are stigmatized in the Chinese-speaking world. People there have trouble distinguishing between the syllable-initial unaspirated /t/ and /d/, phonetic sounds which are common in Indian English.